# useSWRInfinite hook weird bug/error when changing query parameters

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr, nginfinitescroll

So I am trying to implement infinite scroll using `useSWRInfinite` hook of `swr` in `Next.js`.

```
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
import useSWRInfinite = 'swr/infinite';

const API_ENDPOINT = "example.com/api/movies";

export function Scroller() {

const router = useRouter();

const searchParams = useSearchParams();

const genreFilter = searchParams.get("genres");

const getKey = (page) => [API_ENDPOINT, genres, page];

const fetcher = (key) => fetch(key[0] + new URLSearchParams({ genres: key[1], page: key[2] }));

const { data, size, setSize, isLoading, mutate } = useSWRInfinite(getKey,fetcher);

return (

<div> 

    {GENRES.map((g) => (
      <button
        onClick={() => {
         /* Some logic that updates the route with new parameters/genre */
        }}
       />
      ))}

</div>

      <div>
        {data.movies.map((movie) => (
           <div> {movie.name} </div>
        ))}

   {/* infinite scroll logic that on trigger call () => setSize(s => s+1 ) */}

      </div>

)}
```

**Bug that I see in my code:**

Let's say upon page load it has default `genre: Action`.

So when I open the page and scroll everything is working fine but when I change the `genre` to e.g: `Comedy` by `button` click only first page gets loaded for new genre Comedy and upon scrolling no new page gets fetched instead new pages keeps getting added to default genre `Action`.

**Solutions I tried:**

First of all, I am new to using `swr` and this is my first proect with it.

1. Call `setSize(0)` on genre change.
2. Call `mutate([])` on genre change.
3. Call **both** above methods on genre change

But nothing works.

Comment: I found my own solution while reviewing your code. :) Thanks